# laravel product stock and quantity

Tags: laravel, model-view-controller, model

I new in this. and have problem which probably easy for you.
there is a 3 table by name [bill , bill products , product service]
when create a bill, quantity add to bill products and product service.
when update a bill , quantity add or minus to bill products and product service.
but when i destroy a bill , quantity just minus of bill products and not product service

```
   public function update(Request $request, Bill $bill)
    {
                $products = $request->items;

                for ($i = 0; $i < count($products); $i++) {
                    $billProduct = BillProduct::find($products[$i]['id']);

                    if ($billProduct == null) {
                        $billProduct             = new BillProduct();
                        $billProduct->bill_id    = $bill->id;
                        Utility::total_quantity('minus',$products[$i]['quantity'],$products[$i]['item']);
                    }
                    else{
                        Utility::total_quantity('minus',$billProduct->quantity,$billProduct->product_id);
                    }

    public function destroy(Bill $bill)
    {
        if (\Auth::user()->can('delete bill')) {
            if ($bill->created_by == \Auth::user()->creatorId()) {
                $bill->delete();
                if ($bill->vender_id != 0) {
                    Utility::userBalance('vendor', $bill->vender_id, $bill->getTotal(), 'debit');
                }
                BillProduct::where('bill_id', '=', $bill->id)->delete();
```

help me whit destroy method to minus produce service

thank you

Answer (score 0):

Add this relation to your `Bill` model:

```php
public function productServices()
{
    return $this->hasManyThrough(ProductService::class, BillProduct::class, 'bill_id', 'id', 'id', 'product_service_id');
}
```

then use the relation to minus the quantity:

```php
$productServices = $bill->productServices;

foreach ($productServices as $productService) {
    $productService->quantity -= $productService->quantity;
    $productService->save();
}
```

Comment: thanks l try and let you know